# Solve $\frac{dx}{x(c'_1y-2y^2)}=\frac{dy}{y(c'_1y-y^2-2x^3)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A second family of characteristic curves comes from 
$$\frac{dx}{x(c'_1y-2y^2)}=\frac{dy}{y(c'_1y-y^2-2x^3)}$$
The solution of this ODE is :

$y=\frac{c'_1}{2}\pm \sqrt{x^3+\frac{(c'_1)^2}{4}+c_2}$

$\left(y-\frac{c'_1}{2}\right)^2-x^3-\frac{(c'_1)^2}{4}=c_2$

How do I solve this ODE?
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y(c'_1y-y^2-2x^3)}{x(c'_1y-2y^2)}$$

This equation is not exact.

This is not a homogeneous equation. So, I can't use the transformation $u=y/x.$

I used the Integrating formulas for $Mdx+Ndy=0$ equation $\frac{N_x-M_y}{M}$  and $\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}.$ It was not handy.
Is there any analytical method to solve this?

Comment: It seems to me a factor x is missing . It's $xc_3$ in the final answwer if I am not wrong

Comment: It was a doubt on this solution https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432235/find-the-general-integral-of-pxz-2y2-z-qyz-y2-2x3

Comment: I see Math-Geek. I posted my answer and how to get the final result. In the link you provided I see no calculation so I don't know where it could be wrong

Answer (score 1):

I used $k$ for the constant.
$$ky-y^2-2x^3=x(k-2y)y'$$
Complete the square on LHS:
$$-(y-\dfrac k2)^2-2x^3+\dfrac {k^2}{4}=- 2x (y-\dfrac k2)(y-\frac k 2)'$$
Substitute $v=y-\dfrac k 2$
$$-v^2-2x^3+\dfrac {k^2}{4}=- 2x vv'$$
$$v^2+2x^3-\dfrac {k^2}{4}= x(v^2)'$$
Substitute $u=v^2$ and solve.
$$xu'-u=2x^3-\dfrac {k^2}{4}$$
$$\left ( \dfrac ux \right)'=2x-\dfrac {k^2}{4x^2}$$
Integrate.
$$u=x^3+\dfrac {k^2}{4}+cx$$
$$v^2=x^3+\dfrac {k^2}{4}+cx$$
Finally:
$$\boxed {y(x)=\frac k 2\pm \sqrt {x^3+\dfrac {k^2}{4}+cx}}$$